# Change default Math font in Word for Mac? I can do the same in Word for Windows?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, equation-editor

I downloaded a math font that I was able to set as default in MS Word Windows via the **Equation Options** settings. However, this settings box doesn't seem to exist in the Mac version of Word.

Can someone tell me how to access this settings, or change the default math font via the Normal.dotm template (or even command line, if that's possible)?

System info:

- Windows 11 Home 22H2 - Word Version 2302 (Build 16130.20306)
- MacOS Ventura 13.0.1 - Word for Mac Version 16.71 (23031200)

[image]

Comment: Please add more details like the version of the operative system and the version of Word for Mac that  you are using. P.S. At this time I don't know the answer for this specific question but I know that several features of Office products that are available in Windows aren't available in  Mac. Checkout the resources for end-users of Word for Mac and also take a look to [apple.se].

Comment: FWIW On the Windows version of Word ou can use VBA to specify a different Math font, e.g. here  can use ActiveDocument.OMathFontName = "DejaVu Math TeX Gyre" to switch to a font  I have installed, and = "Cambria Math to switch back again.

But on the Mac version, there is no equivalent dialog box, even in Word->Preferences. If I try to use equivalent VBA, I just get a 5844 error with every Math font I have tried, *except* when I use the name "Cambria Math". Probably worth trying your font name and obvious variations, but my guess is that it won't work...

Comment: ...
One thing to bear in mind about Word on Mac is that it is *more picky* about fonts than the Windows version. But I've never come across anything in Microsoft's documentation that even specifies what a font has to do to be a "Math Font" even on Windows.